# Automatically add a label to GitLab issue with commit

Tags: gitlab

Is it somehow possible to automatically add a label to GitLab issue in the git commit message? I know that it is possible to close issue by message `fix #123`, but how to add label to issue, for example, "Testing"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible natively. The only thing you can do is mention the issue 'Fixes/Closes #123' as you mentioned.

If you *really* need to do this, then you *could* potentially do it as part of a custom server-side hook. You would have to interact with the GitLab API to add/manage the labels, but it would be possible. You can learn more about this in [Custom Hooks Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html).

However, I generally recommend avoiding custom hooks. Especially ones that interact with an API as strange things can happen. For example, if you call an API in a `pre-receive` hook and that connection hangs, your push also hangs. It's not quite so bad for a `post-receive` but there could still be problems if a `post-receive` hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks you, made by [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html)